# MySql, how correctly create sql query for order and pagination

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, where-clause

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(160) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `categoryId` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `content` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `carId` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `userId` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `coverUrl` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `costAmount` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `costCurrency` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mileage` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `searchContent` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

```
INSERT INTO posts (`id`, title, categoryId, content, createdAt, updatedAt, carId, userId, mileage, coverUrl, costAmount, costCurrency, `searchContent`) VALUES
(129, 'Вытащил двигатель с авто, подтёки масла', 21, '', 1664353399, 1664353399, 68, 17, 228500, 'img1', 13000, 'uah', 'text'),
(152, 'Вытащил двигатель с авто, подтёки масла', 14, '', 1639699200, 1664359803, 68, 17, 228500, 'img1', 13000, 'uah', 'text'),
(165, 'Вытащил двигатель с авто, подтёки масла', 14, 'text'),
(111, 'Скол на новом лобовом', 21, 'test', 1664304339, 1664304339, 68, 17, 227700, 'img1', 0, 'usd', 'text'),
(130, 'Скол на новом лобовом', 21, 'test', 1664353423, 1664353423, 68, 17, 227700, 'img1', 0, 'usd', 'text'),
(141, 'Скол на новом лобовом', 21, 'test', 1664354165, 1664354165, 68, 17, 227700, 'img1', 0, 'usd', ''),
(166, 'Скол на новом лобовом', 14, 'test', 1639180800, 1664372713, 68, 17, 227700, 'img1', 0, 'usd', ''),
(112, 'Замена лобового', 21, 'test', 1664304427, 1664304427, 68, 17, 227500, 'img1', 10500, 'uah', ''),
(118, 'Замена левой фары после дтп', 19, 'test', 1664304860, 1664304860, 68, 17, 227500, 'img1', 3, 'usd', '');
```

I ordered mileage like DESC. but i have a pagination(lazy), and

I have sort by mileage, but I don't know how to make pagination correctly, if mileage
they are the same, but the IDs for them may be different

Example, if mileage = 227700(please, see image from link) and last id = 130,
how do I get the next list after the id 130? it should be 141 and other.

(:qp0 -> id from GET parameter)

If i try (with lastId 130 from GET parameter)

```
 posts.carId = 68 and posts.id < 130 and posts.mileage < 227700
```

or

```
posts.carId = 68 and posts.id < 130
```

it won't return me the next sort ids, only the ones below

My sql query now: (:qp0 -> id from GET parameter)

```
SELECT
    posts.id,
    posts.title,
    posts.categoryId,
    posts.content,
    posts.userId,
    posts.createdAt,
    posts.mileage,
    posts.costAmount,
    posts.costCurrency,
    posts.coverUrl,
    user.username,
    user.country,
    user.avatar,
    user.city,
    categories.id AS categoryId,
    categories.name,
    post_counter.comments,
    post_counter.likes
FROM
    posts
INNER JOIN user ON USER.id = posts.userId
LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = posts.categoryId
LEFT JOIN post_counter ON post_counter.postId = posts.id
WHERE
    posts.carId = 68 and posts.id < :qp0
ORDER BY
    posts.mileage
DESC
LIMIT 6
```

how should I do pagination in this case without `limit` and `offset`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @KenWhite i do this. thanks.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. Please provide the DDL and DML (CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements), which can be copied and pasted and used to create test data to use to try to help you. Images are useless in any form.

Comment: @KenWhite ohh okay, understand

Comment: Before you go too far down this road, typically pagination is done in a report writer tool on top of your SQL layer.  **Normally**, you run your entire result set at once in SQL and return it in a cursor that your report writer logic can access row by row to create the pagination you want.  This seems a little inside-out, with your report writer calling the data base for each new page load of data.

Comment: @KenWhite now my question correctly. tanks for help!

Comment: *How do I get the next list after the id `130`? it should be `141` and other.* Don't you just want `where posts.id > :qp0` instead of `where posts.id < :qp0`?

Comment: @GMB, but if id was not 141, for example 98? I don't know what the next PK(id) will be.

Comment: You just need your application to keep track of the latest pk that it fetched. Then, you can just pass that value to the inequality condition when running the query, so you get the next page.